# Is it possible to apply in app purchasing as well as ads on single android app?

Tags: android, admob, ads, android-inapp-purchase

Recently I made my first android app and now I want to upload it on play store but I have basic idea about revenue model of play store so can you please tell me is it possible to apply both ads as well as in app purchase for my app so that I will easily manage my revenue from it?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can integrate ads and InApp purchase at same time :) It helps you in monetising your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can display advertisement and at the same time you can also integrate in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate and display both in-app purchase and advertisement services in your app at the same time.